# AngularJS router config, passing name key pairs after variable

Tags: angularjs, routes, key-value

I have a working router config in Angular JS  where I can route navigation based on variable value. I want to extend it by passing key value pair. I searched for it but couldnt find anything.
Below is my routing config

```
    //ROUTING Configuration
    $router.config([
        {path: '/', component: 'pageHome'},
        {path: '/pageHome', component: 'pageHome'}, 
        {path: '/ediStatusDisplay', component: 'ediStatusDisplay'},
        {path: '/ediStatusDisplay/:selectedEntryId', component: 'ediStatusDisplay'},
        {path: '/pageNimbus', component: 'pageNimbus'}
    ]);
```

I would like to extend `/ediStatusDisplay/:selectedEntryId` by passing key value pair so that I can show filtered results.
Apologies if my question sounds entirely stupid or not enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

use run and config

```
.run(
['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
])

.config(
['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$rootScopeProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScopeProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('app.ediStatusDisplay', {
            url: '/ediStatusDisplay/:selectedEntryId',
            templateUrl: 'ediStatusDisplay.html',
            resolve: ...,
            params: {
                title: '...'
            },
        })
}])
```